# MGLMapView hides / fails to load annotations when I change map style (Mapbox)

Tags: ios, xcode, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have just started using the latest released version of Mapbox for iOS, and have setup a map with annotations successfully. The annotations needed custom images based upon a priority value passed by the API. To do this I am using imageForAnnotation as follows:

```
- (MGLAnnotationImage *)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView imageForAnnotation:(id <MGLAnnotation>)annotation
{
    CustomAnnotation *custom = (CustomAnnotation *)annotation;

    NSString *name = nil;
    if (custom.priority == 1 || custom.priority == 2)
        name = @"dot_red";
    else if (custom.priority == 3)
        name = @"dot_orange";
    else if (custom.priority > 3)
        name = @"dot_yellow";
    else if (custom.priority == -11)
        name = @"dot_purple";

    MGLAnnotationImage *annotationImage = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationImageWithIdentifier:name];

    if ( ! annotationImage)
    {
        UIImage *annoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
        annotationImage = [MGLAnnotationImage annotationImageWithImage:annoImage reuseIdentifier:name];
    }

    return annotationImage;
}
```

However, when I change the map style all of the annotations disappear, the map change code is below:

```
[_mapView setStyleURL:kMapSatelliteStyleURL];
            [button setTitle:@"Regular" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.tag = 1;
```

Now when I pan around the map, I notice that the following pops up in the debug window '{Worker}[Sprite]: Can't find sprite named'. This is apparently an issue caused by the asynchronous loading (Source: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/1877), however, the suggested workaround is to implement imageForAnnotation which I do anyway.

I have attached 3 screenshots below of me toggling the map type:

[image: Before Toggle]

[image: After Toggle]

[image: Back Again]

As you can see, even when toggling back to the original map again the images never re-appear. The annotations are definitely being added again (subsection of the broken in to imageForAnnotation po below):

```
po mapView.annotations
<__NSArrayI 0x7fc1b8dec650>(
<CustomAnnotation: 0x7fc1b8b4b450>,
<CustomAnnotation: 0x7fc1b3df6780>
)
```

Has anyone else come across this issue and know how to fix it? I am wondering whether the changing of map style re-orders the map layers, therefore annotations are drawn below the map tiles?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, there is a ticket here:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/1488

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering whether the changing of map style re-orders the map layers, therefore annotations are drawn below the map tiles?

This doesn't sound right. Please [open a ticket](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/new) so that we can address this directly.